# 2 Callbacks in 1 EXTI function?

Tags: c, callback, gpio, stm32f4

Somewhat new to programming with stm32f4 in C.

I have a main (.c and .h) file and an interrupt handler file (.c) which has my call back functions. My problem is that I have to use 2 pins (e.g. A13 and A14), therefore, they use the same EXTI15_10_IRQHandler:

```
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void) {
// Use function to differentiate between the two?
callback1(13);   
callback2(14);
```

}

Would this work for the individual pin call backs? If so, why does it work?

TIA! Please note I cannot post further code as it will be part of a larger project :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the reference manual where everything is described.
2. Simply check which line has triggered the interrupt.

```
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void) {
// Use function to differentiate between the two?
if(EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 13)) {clear_pending(13);callback1(13);} 
if(EXTI->PR1 & (1 << 14)) {clear_pending(14);callback2(14);}
```

3. Before you ask how to write `clear_pending` (or where to find ..), go back to the point `1.` Then write it yourself. If you still do not know how to write it - go to point `1.` and read the EXTI chapter more carefully. Repeat until success

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had a read through the reference manual for stm32f429zi (what I need to use) and there was no mention of clear_pending. Any other pointers that might help?

Comment: @CoffeeDrinker101 of course there will be no mention of 'clear_pending` (do not use search only **read**) but there is the information **how** to clear the pending bit. When you read it, then writing `clear_pending` function will be trivial